# How to run a function automatically for a classes using $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I currently have a function that runs on mouse enter. On '.tip-icon' mouseenter I have a css change happening. But there are 3 different '.tip-icon'. And the property change only happens when you hover over each one. How do I set this css change for each individual one automatically so I don't need to mouse over each one to fix it?

Each '.tip-icon' has a different height, that's why I use $(this). So in the end the 3 different '.tip-icon' will have their own unique css change.

```
$('.tip-icon').mouseenter(function(){
    var toolHeight = $(this).siblings('.tip-group').children('.tip-message').height();
    $(this).css('top', (toolHeight/2)-6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(function() {

    $('.tip-icon').css('top', function(){
        var toolHeight = $(this).siblings('.tip-group').children('.tip-message').height();
        return (toolHeight/2)-6;
    });

});
```

Comment: Ah, so that's how to make a function

Comment: You can take a look at [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) form more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change .mouseenter to .each

```
$('.tip-icon').each(function(){
    var toolHeight = $(this).siblings('.tip-group').children('.tip-message').height();
    $(this).css('top', (toolHeight/2)-6);
});
```